# Phonegap Not Updating Application's Icon on Android

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an application using phonegap on netbeans and now that is it finally ready I have loaded on Google Play.
When I download the app from google play for some reason it still shows the default phonegap icon even though I have changed the `config.xml`

This is the relevant portion of my `config.xml`:

```
 <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" />

    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" gap:role="default" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" gap:role="default" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" gap:role="default" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" gap:role="default" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />
```

If anyone has an idea for why this happens, i would be glad to hear! Thanks!

Comment: sometimes this may happen, to resolve, remove app from you phone and do remember to clean your project. Install again.

Comment: How could i clean my project?

Comment: If you are using eclipse, on Top bar goto Project->Clean

Answer (score 0):

It may well be a caching issue. For me, I uninstalled the app and powered off the device. When it was switched back on I reinstalled and the icon inside Application Manager (the only icon not correct) was now the right one.